# CSS Color table based on input in each row

Tags: css, colors, styling, css-tables

Would it be possible to color each table rows based on a input in a specific column for each row?

Example, if:

B1 = 1 // Red row
B2 = 1 // Red row
B3 = 3 // Blue row
B4 = 2 // Green row
B5 = 1 // Red row

And so on?
It's a datatable and there will automatically be filled new rows into the table, these should also be coloured after the system.

Comment: This would require some javascript, would that be alright

Comment: Hi @marcusshep, I guess yes - if that's the solution. I'm horrible in javascript..

Answer (score 0):

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/farhadB/4gd62wwu/3/)

```
    var dataSet = [['Dadar', 'lmsSenitaD', 'Atul salaskar', '9876543210', '', 'Not Joined', '10/01/2014', '', 'Come back and Join', 'Mobile', 'Times','1'],
['Aundh', 'Rashmi', 'Preeti Gupta', '9876543210', '', 'Not Joined', '10/01/2014', '', 'Will Discuss with Family', 'Online Campaign', 'Iksula','2'],
['Do@Home_Thane', 'Rashmi', 'Mitali Gupta', '9876543210', '', 'Joined - Old Date', '10/01/2014', '20/08/2014', 'Come back and Join', 'Online Campaign', 'Iksula','4']];

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#demo').html('<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>');

    $('#example').dataTable({
        "data": dataSet,                
        "columns": [
                        { "title": "Center" },
                        { "title": "Call Executive" },
                        { "title": "Name" },
                        { "title": "Mobile" },
                        { "title": "Phone" },
                        { "title": "Status" },
                        { "title": "Appt Date" },
                        { "title": "Joined Date" },
                        { "title": "Remark" },
                        { "title": "Source" },
                        { "title": "Publisher" },
                        { "title": "css" },
                      ]
                      ,
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            var css = aData[aData.length - 1];
            if (css == "1") {
                $(nRow).addClass('gradeN');
            }
            else if(css == "2") {
                $(nRow).addClass('gradeC');
            }
            else{
                $(nRow).addClass('gradeM');
            }

        }
```

Comment: Would it be possible to make a jsfiddle, so I could see an example in action? Then it would be easier for me to integrate in my own.. I'm such a rookie..

Comment: Wait a little for createing

Comment: Thanks in advance!

Comment: An example is made for you click on a demo

Comment: Thanks for taking your time. I will try to make it work in my dataset!

Comment: You can collect 'data' from any source

Comment: just use -------                 ,
        "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
            var css = aData[aData.length - 1];
            if (css == "1") {
                $(nRow).addClass('gradeN');
            }
            else if(css == "2") {
                $(nRow).addClass('gradeC');
            }
            else{
                $(nRow).addClass('gradeM');
            }

Comment: If it was helpful . please approve and vote for help others - thanks e lot